# Matching multiple pattern in Ant replaceregexp task

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, ant, build

I have a task in my Ant build script for adding a parameter to the `src` attribute to all `<script>` tags in jsp files.

```
       <replaceregexp flags="gi">               
            <fileset dir="${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/jsp" >   
                <filename name="*.jsp"/>
            </fileset>                  
            <regexp pattern=".js&quot;>"/>
            <substitution expression=".js?param=${pValue}&quot;>"/>         
        </replaceregexp>
```

I want to extend this to all `href` attributes of `<link rel="stylesheet">` tags in all jsps. When I tried to add one more `<regexp>` as

```
<regexp pattern=".css&quot;>"/>
    <substitution expression=".css?param=${pValue}&quot;>"/>
```

in the same `<replaceregexp>`, I am getting error 
`Only one regular expression is allowed.`
How can I do this without using multiple `<replaceregexp>` blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one expression:

```
  <regexp pattern=".(js|css)&quot;>"/>
    <substitution expression=".\1?param=${pValue}&quot;>"/>
```

Which matches js or css in a capturing group and uses the captured value in the substitution.

Comment: By tbe way is that leading . in the pattern intended to match just a '.' character? If so it needs to be escaped.